# Can you add inline base64 encoded image to a Mandrill template?

Tags: html, email, mandrill

Does anyone know if and how-to add a Base64 encoded image to a Mandrill Template.

I use a Mandrill template to make sure all my emails have the same look and feel and I have a simple and small logo which I'd prefer to add to my template following these recommendations:
http://help.mandrill.com/entries/25252978-Tips-for-using-images-in-Mandrill-emails

However i'm unsure on where and how to add the neccesary code in my HTML template. Anyone have an idea if it's possible and how-to do it?

Thx

Answer (score 14):

I have probably found the answer to my own questions.

NO - Mandrill doesn't allow you to add an inline image or to upload the image attachment as code to the template.

SOLUTION - you need to add the array [images] to the $message as suggested in the API.

Here is an PHP example function to do it:

```html
// Add cid image to $message
function add_email_logo($message) {
  $logo = array (
    'images' => array (
      array (
              'type' => 'image/png',
              'name' => 'logo',
              'content' => 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA....etc.'
      )
    )
  );

  return array_merge( $message, $logo);
}
```

and use the image src="cid:{name}"

```html
<img src="cid:logo"/>
```

Comment: Hi, I included <img src="cid:logo"> in my html template, but when I checked the sent email in mandrill outbound activity, i found the image data didn't get attached properly. Instead, it just show '<img src="cid:logo">' plain text in the html. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the middle of the page you link to it tells you that you can use the `img` tag with base64 encoded images

> Include images as inline attachments with your API calls using the
>   images parameter. You'll need to provide the image name (Content-ID),
>   the content (as a base64 encoded string), and the image MIME type.
>   Reference the image name in the 'src' in your HTML content:

```
<img src="cid:image_name">
```

The `src` attribute is using a [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). The general format is

```
<img src="data:(MIME TYPE);base64,(IMAGEDATA BASE 64 ENCODED)">
```

Heres the list of image [media types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_image)

> image/gif
>   image/jpeg
>   image/pjpeg
>   image/png
>   image/svg+xml
>   image/vnd.djvy
>   image/example

The esiest way to get the base64 encoded image already in html tag form is to use a converter online. Googling [base64 encode image](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=base64%20encode%20image#q=base64+encode+image) yeild plenty of results that have this capability.

Comment: yes, but... Mandrill / Gmail doesn't like the inline version. Any other ideas?

Comment: Support using `code`<img src="data:[mime];base64;[base64data]>`code` for email clients is very poor.  You won't get displayed on gmail, yahoo, or modern versions of outlook.  If for some reason you must inline, use `code`<img src="cid:imagename">`code`.

Here's some stats about email client support for inlining images without using cid:  [line](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3927/embedded-images-in-html-email).  The ran tests in 2013, but those results are still valid for the most recent versions of those clients in 2015.

Answer (score 0):

In Mandril example

```
<img src="cid:image_name">
```

Should be replaced with

```
<img src="cid:image_name" />
```

Else, image will be just attached to mail, not shown inside

Answer (score 0):

It's also very important to note that the `images[].content` & `attachments[].content` property must be **a base64 string without any `data:(MIME TYPE);base64,` construction in the beginning, just a string**