# Convert files to base64 string to send as attachment through android application

Tags: android, base64, email-attachments

I creating an application in which I am using mandrill app API to send emails. Emails without attachment are delivering, but when I attach image to it, it is received as damaged image at receiver side. Here it is required to convert file into base64 string to pass in json array. I used this code:

```
public static String encodeImagetoBase64(Bitmap img) {
    Bitmap image = img;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteOStream);
    byte[] b = byteOStream.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.e("Look", imageEncoded);
    return imageEncoded;

}
```

So can anyone tell me the solution, why image is getting damaged.
Similarly I also want to convert files with extension ".txt,.doc,.docx,.pptx,.pdf,.xls" etc as attachment, so please suggest me any source for that. Thanx

Comment: Did you try using Base64.URL_SAFE instead of Base64.DEFAULT?
How is your image processed at the 'receiver side'?

Comment: It's something random colors., I didnot tried Base64.URL_SAFE, I will try it and let you know,

Comment: URL_SAFE is commonly used when transferring data on the web, it is slightly different from DEFAULT implementation and far more likely to be used by Mandrill, you can read more theory in the relevant [RFC4648](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#page-7).

Comment: It does not solve the issue. Before using URL_SAFE some distorted/damaged(image with random colors) image was visible, but now it doesn't show any image

Comment: Asking out of pure interest, can you paste a sample of the distortions when DEFAULT is used? Is it like white noise or the same image, but damaged?

Comment: Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26722890/5908572), maybe it will work in inline mode, if you specify the mime type explicitly as image/jpeg

Comment: I did mention image/jpeg.in mime field.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this method and it is working:

```
 public static String getFileBinary(String uploadFilePath) {
        String encodedString = "0";
        if (uploadFilePath.length() < 2)
            return encodedString;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFilePath);//You can get an inputStream using any IO API
            byte[] bytes;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int bytesRead;
            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bytes = output.toByteArray();
            encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

        } catch (IOException es) {

        }
        return encodedString;
    }
```

Comment: Now I am getting attachments except the .txt files. But other files I am getting are without extensions. and with name "noname".. In inbox, only pdf file's contents are visible, but after downloading it's without extension.

Comment: Ofcourse. This is only for getting binaryData of your file , For sending attachments via Mandrill you still need to mention file name and file extension too.

Comment: Ohhh... Then how should I do that..??

Comment: I can't upload as I don't have enough reputation points.distorted image is just like layers of image

Comment: The link I just sent you is a official link found on mandrill website, I guess if you examine it good enough you can find your answer there. Further than that I m sorry that I cannot help you.